# How to return matching nested elements in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Let's say this is the complete document

```
{
    "_id": "63aadd124fabe6c7f5cb3af5",
    "url": "https://github.com",
    "sender": "username@gmail.com",
    "recipients": [
        {
            "email": "recipient1@gmail.com",
            "code": "XY231",
            "position": 54,
        },
        {
            "email": "recipient1@gmail.com",
            "code": "XY231",
            "position": 48,
        },
        {
            "email": "recipient2@gmail.com",
            "code": "AB124",
            "position": 114,
        }
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "page": 0,
            "recipient": {
              email: "recipient1@gmail.com",
              code: "XY231",
            }
        },
        {
            "page": 2,
            "recipient": {
              email: "recipient2@gmail.com",
              code: "AB124",
            }
        },
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-01-11T16:02:56.126Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-14T09:49:41.962Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want my query to return based on `recipients.code: XY231` and if the `recipients.code` doesn't match any element, it should return null / empty array :

```
{
    "_id": "63aadd124fabe6c7f5cb3af5",
    "url": "https://github.com",
    "sender": "username@gmail.com",
    "recipients": [
        {
            "email": "recipient1@gmail.com",
            "code": "XY231",
            "position": 54,
        },
        {
            "email": "recipient1@gmail.com",
            "code": "XY231",
            "position": 48,
        }
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "page": 0,
            "recipient": {
              email: "recipient1@gmail.com",
              code: "XY231",
            }
        },
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-01-11T16:02:56.126Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-14T09:49:41.962Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I tried with `$unwind` and `$project`, but I don't think it caters to my need, as it returns the matching query but only one element, like this:

```
{
    "_id": "63aadd124fabe6c7f5cb3af5",
    "url": "https://github.com",
    "sender": "username@gmail.com",
    "recipients": {
            "email": "recipient1@gmail.com",
            "code": "XY231"
     },
    "properties": {
            "page": 0,
            "recipient": {
              email: "recipient1@gmail.com",
              code: "XY231",
            }
             {
            "email": "recipient1@gmail.com",
            "code": "XY231"
        },
     },
    "createdAt": "2023-01-11T16:02:56.126Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-14T09:49:41.962Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {recipients: {$elemMatch: {"code": "XY231"}}}},
  {$set: {
      recipients: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$recipients",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.code", "XY231"]}
        }
      },
      properties: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$properties",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.recipient.code", "XY231"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ugZ-2HB56rl)

Comment: That works perfectly to a certain extent. But if there's no matching code is found, it should return `[ ]` or null, instead it returns the main document keys with empty `recipients` and `properties`

Comment: I understood you want: `recipients:[]`. If you want just `[]`, that's easy, just add one more `$match` step at the beginning. Answer is updated

Comment: No I think you got me wrong. I meant if there's no matching recipients and properties are found, i,e., if `recipients: []` and `properties: []` then I have to send `null` as the response, so I did the following condition check in my code
`if (data.recipients.length === 0 &&
    data.properties.length === 0) return null`